# Twisted with multiple ports, protocols, and reactors

Tags: python, network-programming

Will twisted support listening on multiple ports, with different 'handlers' (different set of callbacks for each port) at the same time?  Essentially, I want my process to host two servers in one process, each performing a different function.  Would I need to use two reactors to do this?

Comment: One reactor. Always only one reactor per process. But it can listen on multiple ports, serve multiple protocols, run a WebSocket Server on the same port where the HTTP content is served and so on. The reactor is the dispatcher for all the incoming events https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for instance, modifying the [quote server example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.0.0/core/howto/servers.html#auto7) you could add a second instance listening on a different port with a different quote:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor

class QOTD(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        # self.factory was set by the factory's default buildProtocol:
        self.transport.write(self.factory.quote + '\r\n')
        self.transport.loseConnection()


class QOTDFactory(Factory):

    # This will be used by the default buildProtocol to create new protocols:
    protocol = QOTD

    def __init__(self, quote=None):
        self.quote = quote or 'An apple a day keeps the doctor away'

endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8007)
endpoint.listen(QOTDFactory("configurable quote"))

endpoint2 = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8008)
endpoint2.listen(QOTDFactory("another configurable quote"))

reactor.run()
```

Output:

```
$ nc localhost 8007
configurable quote
$ nc localhost 8008
another configurable quote
```

Comment: Awesome answer.  What about if I wanted to throw in something else, like a twisted WebSocket for example.  Could I do that alongside those?

Comment: @horsehair I haven't tried it, but it should work fine. The reactor basically polls each socket and sends the data to the respective protocol when it arrives. Are you using http://autobahn.ws/ ?

Comment: I am trying to determine whether I should use autobahn.ws, but I was starting to think that Twister had built-in functionality that made using autobahn in addition to it redundant.  For a simple WebSocket that just passes messages, at least.  No?

Comment: @horsehair I'm not up to date with the development, but last time I checked the WebSocket branch was still under development

Comment: @PeterGibson, How can I run the demo in daemon mode with twistd ?